# Car not starting after jump

Tags: electrical, battery, ignition, alternator, short

I purchased a Ford Escort from a dealer year ago. I've had battery/ignition/electrical shorts/starting & car dying issues. I've bought a new battery for jumping the old battery everyday. The last jump, the car started but when I shut it off now it won't start. There is no sound, not even a click. My new battery tested dead. I live in the car, now I have no heat and I'm stranded.

Comment: For now, jump it off somebody else's car.  Then, fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. When using an external battery to jump a car, make sure your external battery is getting recharged.
2. You should not need to jump the car everyday, that is not normal, and not healthy.
3. Since you are living in the car, if you are using the cigarette port to power electrical things with the engine off, or even just the lights and radio, that will kill your battery pretty quick.
4. The cause of your electrical problems could be a dead alternator not recharging the battery, it could also be a short somewhere draining battery power.

Answer (score 2):

Starter of your car is gone. Replace carbon brush in your starter or get a used starter